# How to add a new column and insert value that has the relation with another column in dask?

Tags: python, dataframe, dask

I want to do like this,

### Column A

- A
- C
- B
- D

I want to add a new column (Column B), where it will be dependent on column A. Like A = 20, C = 50, B = 23, D = 10,

How can i resolve this in dask?.. Please explain

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what is dask, but it's easy using the `apply` method together with a `lambda function`:

```py
apply_data = {"A": 20, "B": 30, ...}

mydf['B'] = mydf['A'].apply(lambda x: apply_data[x])
```

the output would be something like this:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| A | 20 |
| C | 30 |
| ... | ... |